# C#, is there a variable that takes a class or a way to change a selected class

Tags: c#

Basically what I am trying to do is have one class change a number of a different class based on its own value. However, I also want to change the class that is changed and the class that is acting using something like a variable.

An ideal solution would be variables called selectedClass and actingClass. Where you could say

```
selectedClass = person1, actingClass = person2
```

Then do something like

```
selectedClass.health = selectedClass.health - actingClass.damage
```

and have it pull or change values from the person1 classes or person2 classes. Then be able to change the selectedClass and actingClass for person5 being the actingClass and person15 being the selectedClass and have it get or set those different respective values.

I do not know how to have this functionality without creating a different script for every possible person changing every other possible person. Which would be a time consuming and not very effective solution.

I am sorry if I am overlooking a simple solution. Thanks to anyone in advance for the help!

Comment: Don't you just need a common base class or an interface? See the shapes example at the bottom of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance) or [interfaces here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/).

Comment: Do you really have different classes, or do you have different instances of *one* class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is more or less interfaces:

```
public interface IPerson {
   int Health {get; set;}
   int Damage {get; set;}
}

public class ActionService(){
  public IPerson SelectedClass {get;set;}
  public IPerson ActingClass {get;set;}

  public void Hit()
  {
     this.SelectedClass.Health -= this.ActingClass.Damage;
  }

}
```

And now you can do:

```
public class JackieChan : IPerson {

  public int Health {get;set;} = 120;
  public int Damage {get;set;} = 20;
}

public class Terminator: IPerson {

  public int Health {get;set;} = 500;
  public int Damage {get;set;} = 25;
}

var action = new ActionService { SelectedClass = new JackieChan(), ActingClass = new Terminator() };

action.Hit();
```

Answer (score 4):

First, I think you mistake Class and Object. See [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-class-and-object/)

So in this case `selectedClass` and `actingClass` is actually a reference to an object, not class. You should name it as `selectedPerson`, `actor`.

Since they are reference to object, you can do what you say:

```
var selectedPerson = person1;
var actor = person2;
... change on selectedPerson will affect on person1...

... and you can assign selectedPerson to person 5...
```